# Ask, and you shall receive

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, pattern

Request of me twenty, receive of me twenty.

Request of me sixty, your behest will be fulfilled.

Request of me eighty, you'll be given the same;

but ask for one hundred, and you will get only sixty.

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> minutes?

Because

> 20 minutes is twenty minutes, 60 minutes is sixty minutes, 80 minutes is eighty minutes (or 1:20 hours/minutes), but 1:00 is one hour or only sixty minutes.

More specifically,

> numbers entered into a microwave (that means seconds/minutes instead of minutes/hours, but the idea is the same).

Comment: Precisely! Well, nearly - the intended response was "microwave", but provided the correlation existing between the two, both answers are entirely valid.

Comment: I never used a microwave, so I wouldn't know that part :-) But 100 -> 60 seemed like too much of a coincidence to not be connected to this answer.

Comment: Do most microwaves actually allow you to "request eighty"?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes. In seconds, anyway. And with the specified behavior, all of which applies exactly as described. I expected that to be the answer in fact (and OP’s comment seems to confirm that I was on target).

Comment: Interesting. I'm pretty sure mine doesn't.

Comment: @interoperability I edited my answer to be fully correct based on your comment.